# python mathplotlib for the real data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some real data in python, however I am not able to set the specific step between the values on the y-axis. The plot automaticly, using

```
plt.plot(step, chart, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

looks like this

[image]

But it should look like this (from excel):

[image]

Ive been trying to customize the y axis but I could only set the max and min value. Please give me some ideas how to repare the plot

Kind regards

Comment: Can you post a sample of `step` and `chart`?

Comment: "step" are the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., 200. "chart" are the numbers 2.045408, 2,27245, ... - generally in range from -20 to 40

Comment: my guess is that your numbers are actually strings and so they are treated as categories instead of quantities

Comment: That's why I wanted to see a sample of the data :D

Comment: Yeah it was in string values. Now it works fine, however I dont know why, but in "plt.ylim(-20, 40, 5)", setting specific step (here =5) doesnt work, any suggestions?

Comment: If your values are strings you will not be able to set the range of your axis ticks with ```ylim()```.  if you want to limit the axis convert your values to float. If you are still having this issue after converting to numeric values, please give more details about what isn't working.

Comment: @M-Wi yeah I already converted it into numerical value but im not able to set the step between the values on the axes, for example I got values -10, 0, 10, 20 ... but I want to have -10, -5, 0, 5, ..

Answer (score -1):

Use `plt.ylim()` to set max, min, **and** step size.

Working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
fig = plt.figure()
x = list(range(0,200))
y = [math.sqrt(5*val) for val in x]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.ylim(-20, 40, 10) # set ymin as -20, ymax as 40, and step size of 10
plt.xlim(0, 200, 50)
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: example]

Answer (score -1):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

fig = plt.figure()

axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

axes.set_xlim(0, 200, 50)
axes.set_ylim(-20, 40, 10)

x = list(range(0,200))
y = [math.sqrt(5*val) for val in x]

axes.scatter(x, y, marker="D", label="Serie1")

axes.grid(axis="y", linestyle="--", linewidth=0.5, color=".25", zorder=-10)

axes.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
axes.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
axes.spines["bottom"].set_position("zero")

axes.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]